# how to implement video playback in the collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

I want to develop an demo app to show either video and images on collection view cell, just like Instagram post or [this link](https://medium.com/android-development-by-danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429).  I want, suppose there are two cell and each cell has video.
play only video which cell visible more than other cell and pause other one.
**I know How to implement to play and pause video using AVPlayer**.

I just want to hint what should I do to implement what I asked about.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how check table view cell focus and player set pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075336/how-check-table-view-cell-focus-and-player-set-pause)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698061/12783209). The answer mentions two delegate methods that you can use to achieve the described behavior.

Comment: hello,
in that post , he want to show one video at a time on whole screen. and paging enabled
but I want to show two or more cell video on screen like I give link.